# Local mechanic ok to repair exotics?

Tags: maintenance

I use a local mechanic to repair my Volvo 850 and he does a good job. He has college-level mechanic training and knows how to do basic electronic diagnosis and maintenance. Sometimes there are delays if a special tool involved. For example, in the last repair he tried to set a rear seal with a jerry rig, and when it leaked, he gave up on that idea, ordered the special tool from a dealer, and re-did the procedure. Doing complex electrical troubleshooting is difficult for him. Heavy mechanical stuff, like work on axles and suspensions is his forte. Latches, fasteners, handles and other small mechanisms he cannot do, unless it is a simple replacement.

Anyway, I am thinking of getting one of the newer Aston Martins and I am wondering whether a mechanic like this can maintain it efficiently. Is that futile, and I will need to be finding a $400/hr aircraft-style mechanic, or will the AM more or less be like the Volvo for him?

Comment: If he can't handle a 90s-era Volvo, how is he going to handle a modern Aston Martin? Everything is electronic nowadays.

Comment: Look around for an independent shop that specializes in exotics, specifically Aston Martins. Depending on your location, you might be surprised at the number of shops that fit that criteria. In Dallas, for instance, I know of three different independent shops that do Ferrari work, another that focuses on Lotus. Find your local AM owners club and ask for a referral.

Comment: @DavidLively Ok, so you think it is inadvisable for a local mechanic, even a good one, to work on a car like that and that a specialist is definitely needed?

Comment: @CooterDavenport I wouldn't go that far, but based on your comments about him having difficulty with latches, etc., I'd be wary. Local mechanics are fine - I rarely take my cars to dealerships. BUT, given the potential cost of fixing a big mistake on that car, I'd look for someone that has worked on that model before. On my Boxster, you even needed special tools to do an *alignment* of all things.